# What happens if a user is deleted in redmine?

Tags: redmine

If I delete a user in redmine, what exactly will be deleted and what will stay?

Will the issues that user created be deleted as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you delete a user, there will be a security question if you really want to do it and that it cannot be undone.

Then after deletion, all issues the user made are still there but marked as posted **anonymous**.

So if you also want to delete all posts by this user, you should do this before deleting the user.

Comment: Note that you can also 'disable' a user, which is more secure than deleting it. It can be undone and you still see the user's name in issues and history.